# Blazor WebAssembly App using .NET 5.0 - Google Search - Loading... An unhandled error has occurred. Reload

Tags: c#, azure, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have an Azure hosted Blazor WebAssembly Application that does not give me an error on load for any modern browser.

https://ogglas.com/

However Google sees the following error:

> Loading... An unhandled error has occurred. Reload.

[image]

I have not changed any code and I have waited over a month to see if anything changes but I still see this value.

Using LinkedIn POST INSPECTOR I do get the description I want but I can also see "Alternate values we considered": `An unhandled error has occurred. Reload.` and `Loading...`.

[image]

https://www.linkedin.com/post-inspector/inspect/https:%2F%2Fogglas.com%2F

What can I do to fix this? Could it be due to slow response time or anything similar?

Comment: I don't think any crawler will run WebAssembly. Your `index.html` page is all it will see.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I think you are right but meta description is located in `index.html`.

Comment: Yes, so that is accessible. Like I said. I see no 'but'.

Comment: @HenkHolterman In my mind Google would pick up this description :)

Comment: That's about how Google works. Not about Blazor.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Very true, the question was about the Google result though and technology was mentioned for potential fixes. :)

Comment: @Ogglas I have the same problem. Kinda looks bad and probably drops the likely hood of them clicking the link too

Answer (score 1):

Due to how web crawlers works, serving non-static content like javascript or webassembly to them is not supported. Therefor you would need to send static content instead of serving dynamic content as what blazor does by default.

Here are some related issues:

1. https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/15695

And this might be a good read to get an understanding on how crawlers work:

1. https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/dynamic-rendering